Explicit zero free regions for the Riemann zeta function
Plenty of research has been done on Explicit zero free regions for the Riemann zeta function. My question is
fixing a sufficiently large $T_0$, let's say around $ 10^{10}$ what form can the zero free region take. Explicitly, find constant $C_0>0$ so that all $s=\sigma+it$ with $|T| \geq T_0$ and $\sigma \geq 1-\frac{C_0}{\log T} $ the Riemann zeta function is zero-free. Ideally, I would like the constant $C_0$ to be larger than one, but from what I've seen
for small $T_0$ the constant is less than one

In principle, Olivier Ramare's TME-EMT project should maintain up to date references on these sorts of questions https://tmeemt.github.io/Chest/ , though I do not know how frequently it plans to be updated.  In particular your question is addressed at https://tmeemt.github.io/Chest/Articles/Art08.html

In Appendix A of this preprint, a list of all the state-of-the-art explicit zero-free regions is given. For your purposes, there are two notable zero-free regions.
Firstly, in [1], we have that $C_0=1/5.558691$ holds for $T_0=2$. Unfortunately, even if one tried to improve this result for larger $T_0$, the method involved limits out around $C_0=1/5.5$.
Otherwise, to determine when one can take $C_0=1$, you have to look at the best explicit Vinogradov-Korobov zero-free region due to Bellotti [2]. Namely, Bellotti shows that one has a zero-free region
$$\sigma\ge 1-\frac{1}{53.986(\log |t|)^{2/3}(\log\log |t|)^{1/3}}$$
for all $|t|\geq 3$. For your purposes, this implies that one can take $C_0=1$ for $T_0=\exp(\exp(17.8))\approx 10^{5\cdot 10^7}$. In addition, Bellotti shows that one can not do too much better if $T_0$ is taken larger in her proof, by showing that for sufficiently large $t$ one can only replace the $53.986$ by $48.0718$.
[1] Explicit zero-free regions for the Riemann
zeta-function, M. Mossinghoff, T. Trudgian, A. Yang, Research in Number Theory, 2024.
[2] Explicit bounds for the Riemann zeta function and a new
zero-free region, C. Bellotti, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, 2024.
